# Make a ScrollPane Menu with libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I am making a MenuGame choosing level by `ScrollPane(libGDX)`.
I want to add a Button using `ScrollPane` like the game "Cut the Rop", or "Tap The Frog".
A buttonlevel may be : Locking buttonlevel, rank starlevel (player played that level, and had 1, 2 or 3 stars ..., Unlock buttonlevel.
I had levelimages, lockimage, star and ***I have to make a lot of image for a level (locking Image Level, 0 stars ImageLevel, 1 star Level...)***.
How can I make that buttonlevels more simply ?

Comment: If I understand you right, you are spending a lot of time making images and want a faster way to do it. Not sure what that has to do with `ScrollPane`, but you could make them all at once as a sprite then just use one image.

Comment: I solved my problem. libGDX UI is very useful for me. I create a Button class extends Button class in libGDX, and a can draw anything i want. And final add it into ScrollPane. Thanks for your idea.